# Extracting values from AnalyzeComponentStore?

Tags: powershell

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for the possible answers.
Where I work we have different WS2016 virtual machines and we read that the updates could be a pain due to the very long time they could take and we can't stay a lot with the services down (we have several virtual machines to update soon).
In the same thread we read an advice: cleaning the WinSXS folder could drastically reduce this time.
WS2016 already has this scheduled but it has got a 1 hour timeout so if it takes more than that the process gets killed.
The solution is creating the schedule manually so we made a script for this that checks the current date and the last update date and, if the difference is more than 30 days, it runs the command:

> dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore

and then the command:

> dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

Now the real question...One of the results of AnalyzeComponentStore is:

> Component Store Cleanup Recommended

And the answer could be Yes or No 
Is there a way to check if this value is "Yes" (so launch the StartComponentCleanup) or "No" (so exit from the script)?

Thanks again!

@Doug Maurer...this is the result of the AnalyzeComponentStore

PS C:> dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.3750

Image Version: 10.0.14393.3241

[===========================99.7%========================= ]

Component Store (WinSxS) information:

Windows Explorer Reported Size of Component Store : 8.08 GB

Actual Size of Component Store : 7.94 GB

```
Shared with Windows : 6.12 GB
Backups and Disabled Features : 1.49 GB
Cache and Temporary Data : 323.47 MB
```

Date of Last Cleanup : 2016-09-12 13:40:35

Number of Reclaimable Packages : 0 
Component Store Cleanup Recommended : Yes

The operation completed successfully. 
PS C:>

Comment: Show the full output and you’ll likely get a better answer. Does it have a space before? A colon?

Comment: Thanks. And you just want to know if it says yes or no? None of the other info is important to grab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, I will list two and you can choose the one you like better. Others may offer alternative approaches.

First using `Select-String` - simply pipe the output into select string

```
$output = @'
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool Version: 10.0.14393.3750

Image Version: 10.0.14393.3241

[===========================99.7%========================= ]

Component Store (WinSxS) information:

Windows Explorer Reported Size of Component Store : 8.08 GB

Actual Size of Component Store : 7.94 GB

Shared with Windows : 6.12 GB
Backups and Disabled Features : 1.49 GB
Cache and Temporary Data : 323.47 MB
Date of Last Cleanup : 2016-09-12 13:40:35

Number of Reclaimable Packages : 0
Component Store Cleanup Recommended : Yes

The operation completed successfully.
'@

$output | Select-String "Component Store Cleanup Recommended : (\w*)" | foreach {$_.matches.groups[1].value}
```

I used the outvariable paremeter of Foreach, you could also just assign normally

```
$cleanup = $output | Select-String "Component Store Cleanup Recommended : (\w*)" | foreach {$_.matches.groups[1].value}
```

Second suggestion is to use -Match

```
$cleanup = if($output -match "Component Store Cleanup Recommended : (\w*)"){$matches[1]}
```

Both will end up setting `$cleanup` to the yes/no value you're after.

```
Get-Variable cleanup

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                          
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                          
cleanup                        {Yes}
```

Now you can simply check if it's yes and run the cleanup if so.

```
if($cleanup -eq 'yes'){"run cleanup code"}
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions! I will try them asap!